# Results are not visible when using scrapy with python

Tags: python, scrapy

I was learning how to scrape with scrapy using python . The result shows that [finished in 1.1s] when i run it through sublimetext, im not able to see what i scrapped. im also not able to see a json file which shows wha i scrapped. can someone help? what i wrote for the code is present below.

```
import scrapy




class Scrapping(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myscrape'
    start_urls = ['https://indianexpress.com/section/india/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.css('div.nation'):
            yield{
                Headlines : first.css('h2.title').getall()
            }
            
    

Scrapping()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try adding the following which helps produce an output:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

process = CrawlerProcess(
    settings = {
        'FEED_URI':'stuff.jl',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'jsonlines'
            }
process.crawl(Scrapping)
process.start()
```

Check the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html) for other exports available.

Here are the amendments to your code as you've made a few errors:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class Scrapping(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myscrape'
    start_urls = ['https://indianexpress.com/section/india/']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = response.css('div.nation')
        
        for product in data:
            stuff = product.css('h2.title').getall()
            
            yield {
                'Headlines':stuff
            }
            
process = CrawlerProcess(
    settings = {
        'FEED_URI':'stack3.jl',
        'FEED_FORMAT':'jsonlines'
    }
)
process.crawl(Scrapping)
process.start()
```

Output:

```
{
    "Headlines": ["<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/centre-teams-10-states-high-omicron-cases-covid-19-7689812/\">Centre to send teams to 10 states with high Omicron cases, low vaccination</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/pm-modi-pays-tributes-to-vajpayee-on-his-birth-anniversary-7689726/\">PM Modi pays tributes to Vajpayee on his birth anniversary</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/uttarakhand-minister-harak-singh-rawat-resign-bjp-2022-assembly-elections-7689715/\">Minister Harak Singh Rawat threatens to resign in fresh headache for BJP in Uttarakhand</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/vp-naidu-pays-tributes-to-vajpayee-on-his-birth-anniversary-7689652/\">VP Naidu pays tributes to Vajpayee on his birth anniversary</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/prime-minister-narendra-modi-christmas-greetings-twitter-7689569/\">\u2018Recall noble teachings of Jesus Christ\u2019: PM Modi extends Christmas greetings</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/parliament-winter-session-rajya-sabha-centre-opposition-7689541/\">Centre hits out at Oppn over disrupting RS proceedings; respect commanded, not demanded, says Congress</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/rs-150-crore-seized-from-up-businessman-bjp-sp-7689339/\">Rs 150 crore seized from office of UP businessman; BJP, SP trade charges</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/ramnath-goenka-awards-2019-regional-category-7689407/\">Stories on upkeep of dams, mines winners in Regional category</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/ludhiana-blast-burst-water-pipe-vital-clues-feared-washed-away-7689406/\">Ludhiana blast burst water pipe, vital clues feared washed away</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/death-chhattisgarh-living-with-elephants-7689326/\">Death in Chhattisgarh village reshapes living with 43 elephants and crop losses</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/covid-delhi-case-haryana-up-night-curfew-7689314/\">Covid: Rise in Delhi case count, neighbouring Haryana &amp; UP impose night curfew</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/cong-casting-aspersions-on-constitutional-authority-govt-7689337/\">Cong \u2018casting aspersions\u2019 on constitutional authority: govt</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/pm-chairs-meet-of-high-level-panel-on-sri-aurobindos-150th-birth-anniversary-7689313/\">PM chairs first meeting of committee on celebration of 150th birth anniversary of Sri Aurobindo</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/atal-bihari-vajpayee-jaishankar-cold-war-7689273/\">Vajpayee sought modus vivendi with China: Jaishankar</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/india-news-india/third-covid-wave-india-peak-feb-iit-kanpur-7688841/\">Third Covid wave in India may peak in early Feb: IIT-Kanpur study</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/covid-19-developments-up-haryana-night-curfew-curbs-government-warning-7689145/\">India Covid updates: Govt says world seeing fourth surge of cases; UP, Haryana &amp; Maharashtra impose fresh curbs</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/political-pulse/punjab-elections-brahmpura-return-akali-dal-7689208/\">Brahmpura return gives Akali Dal shot in arm ahead of Punjab polls</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/vaccination-not-enough-omicron-doses-7689184/\">50% of Omicron cases were double jabbed, masks and  surveillance must for breaking transmission chain</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/up-elections-covid-omicron-ec-7689182/\">Will take call on holding UP polls next week, says CEC Sushil Chandra</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/haridwar-religious-gathering-fir-waseem-rizvi-7689150/\">Booked for Haridwar meet, ex-UP Shia Waqf Board chief turned Hindu, BJP advocate</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/political-pulse/political-pressure-nitish-kumar-social-reform-yatra-7688958/\">Under political pressure, Nitish Kumar sets out on \u2018social reform\u2019 yatra</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/bihar-prohibition-nitish-kumar-7688621/\">Prohibition won\u2019t be relaxed for those coming to Bihar from elsewhere: Nitish Kumar</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/rahul-gandhi-harish-rawat-meeting-congress-campaign-7688639/\">Rahul placates Rawat: he is leader of Congress campaign, not CM face yet</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/asaduddin-owaisi-video-edited-mislead-distract-haridwar-meet-7688472/\">Asaduddin Owaisi says video of him edited to mislead, to \u2018distract from Haridwar meet\u2019</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>", "<h2 class=\"title\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"https://indianexpress.com/article/india/kerala/two-more-rss-workers-arrested-for-sdpi-leaders-killing-in-kerala-7688359/\">Two more RSS workers arrested for SDPI leader\u2019s killing in Kerala</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h2>"]
}
```